# What does a tomcat error about CsrfPreventionFilter mean?

Tags: java, tomcat, servlet-filters

I found the error in the logs of my application, googling produces very confusing results.
What is this error? How is it possible to workaround or track it down?
Thanks.

Comment: It would be helpful for us (and future googlers who stumbled upon this question) if you copypaste the entire exception and stacktrace.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CsrfPreventionFilter appear in Tomcat7, so please check if your application runs on Tomcat6, but uses lib files of Tomcat7.

Comment: I have moved to Tomcat 7. All ok now. Thanks.